# Getting error while deploying two same web applications with different context in jboss EAP 7.2

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-7

I am trying to deploy same web application with different context on jboss EAP 7.2
Like testOne.war and testTwo.war. My urls will be like

1)http://127.0.0.1:8080/testOne/get.
2)http://127.0.0.1:8080/testTwo/get.

Both wars are deployed properly, but only one url is working fine and other is throwing error by overriding the default server.

```
[org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/testOne' for server 'default-server'
```

it's over ridden by

```
[org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/testTwo' for server 'default-server'
```

In the above senario http://127.0.0.1:8080/testTwo/get. will work fine and http://127.0.0.1:8080/testOne/get will throw exception

```
UT005023: Exception handling request to testOne/get: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.getHeaders()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/glassfish/jersey/server/ContainerRequest, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for interface javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext have different Class objects for the type javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap used in the signature
```

The same is working fine in tomcat 8.5.35

Comment: How are you deploying your applications ? My guess is that you should use the deploy command from jboss-cli and specify the runtime name

Comment: I have copied in jboss-eap-7.2/standalone/deployments and run ./standalone.sh . Deployed through file system

Comment: I tried deploying with jboss-cli also but no luck

Comment: Did you specify a runtime name ? Do you have a jboss-web.xml in your wars ?

Comment: yes, and in jboss-deplyment-structure.xml . I have excluded `<exclude-subsystems>
   <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
   <subsystem name="jpa" />
  </exclude-subsystems>
  <exclusions>
   <module name="javaee.api" />
   <module name="org.jboss.as.jaxrs" />
   <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa" />
  </exclusions>`

Comment: I tried normal simple application with different context. its working fine, I am getting error while deploying my servers

Answer (score 0):

Add below snippet in "jboss-deployment-structure.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
      <dependencies>
        <module name="org.jboss.remote-naming" />
      </dependencies>
    </deployment>
  </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: it looks to be an issue with Wildfly class loading mechanism. Jboss EAP 6.3.3 onwards supports JDK 8.